# keyframe not working in border animation.

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I was just trying to create a simple border animation in CSS-3 , but somehow it seems to fail and not work **[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1362L7qc/)**

CODE:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 4em;
    padding: 2em 5em;
    background: #eee;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 120%;*/
}
a:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    height: 5px;
    display: block;
    background: #c107b4;
}
a:hover:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
    -o-animation-delay: .3s;
    animation-delay: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: borderanim;
    -o-animation-name: borderanim;
    animation-name: borderanim;
}
@-moz-keyframes borderanim {
    from {
        width: 10%;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes borderanim {
    from {
        width: 10%;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Well if instead of using a custom animation, if i do the following :

```
a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 5s;
  -o-transition: width 5s;
  transition: width 5s;
}
```

The border animation works(no keyframes used here though.), it works , but there is glinch. I'd prefer a keyframe animation. Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must assign animation duration to see the change
in your case it animation in 0.0s. Must assign some time to see animation e.g

```
tag-name
{
animation-name:animate;
animation-duration:2s;
}
@keyframes animate
{
from{background:black;}
to{background:white;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `-webkit-animation` instead of  `-webkit-animation-name` and give some animation duration.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spe8kg03/)**

```
a:hover:before {
    -webkit-animation: borderanim 5s;
    -o-animation: borderanim 5s;
    animation: borderanim 5s; }
```